# How to add more than 1 number in a loop in Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I have this loop:

```
for ((i=100;i<1001;i++));
do
     echo $i
     sleep 1
done
```

I want to know how I can add 10 every time the loop repeats instead of adding 1. So I want the loop to look something like this:
110
120
130
140
and keep going until it reaches the limit or stopped!
Thanks

Comment: Change the `i++` to whatever operation you want instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ((i=100;i<1001;i+=10));
do
     echo $i
     sleep 1
done
```

Simply change `++` to `+= 10`

Comment: ;) That's my first answer ever on stackoverflow.

Comment: I am glad you'll remember me! =)